# 75% + 25% doesn't make 100% ... apparently! CSS issue

Tags: css, percentage

I have an image width a width of 75% and a p-box with a width of 25%, but they won't fit in their parent container!

http://jsfiddle.net/bmBnF/4/

Comment: Box Model - http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html

Comment: http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try adjusting this a bit:

```
.flexslider .slides img {
    float: left; /* leave other properties */
}

.flex-caption {
    width: 16%; /* leave others - width is 16% because you have a 2% padding around all sides ( 16 width + 2 left + 2 right */ )
}
```

Comment: I'll just make a short WUHU! http://jsfiddle.net/bmBnF/6/ seems to work with the float:left, and leaving the width to 20% :)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that in CSS `width` actually means "content width". Padding and borders do not count, so you have to adjust (reduce) your widths to compensate for them.

See [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmBnF/3/). Notice that I changed the `20%` width to `16%` (compensating the `2%` margins on each side), and changed `80%` to `79%` to account for rounding issues.

Note: in newer browsers you can force the use of the "traditional" (Microsoft) box-model for specific elements, then `width` would mean the full width, including padding and borders. See Cthulhu's answer for an example.

Comment: But i don't have any padding or margins anywhere? And im even using CSS reset to eliminate that :)

Comment: You have `padding: 2%` on `.flex-caption`.

Comment: can't see anything on JSFiddle for any of these :-(

Comment: @the0ther github doesn't work as an external src for javascript in jsfiddle anymore. Try http://jsfiddle.net/bmBnF/22/

Answer (score 2):

Just add `-webkit-box-sizing:border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing:border-box;` to .flex-caption:

http://jsfiddle.net/Cthulhu/bmBnF/2/

This is the Box Model Bug, you can read about it on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug

Comment: That still doesn't do the trick... The caption box still floats beneath the image :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I provided an update to your own jsfiddle which works fine with the solution I gave you. Can you send more details?